# How to make ETW work with ARM Template for VM Scale Sets for Service Fabric using EtwProviders

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-service-fabric, azure-diagnostics

Here is the template for VM Scale Set that is created by the azure portal as part of creating a service fabric cluster with some elements omitted for simplicity.

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets",
  "properties": {
    "upgradePolicy": {
      "mode": "Automatic"
    },
    "virtualMachineProfile": {
      "extensionProfile": {
        "extensions": [
          {
            "name": "[concat('ServiceFabricNodeVmExt','_vmNodeType0Name')]"
          },
          {
            "name": "[concat('InstallNET62VmExt','_vmNodeType0Name')]"
          },
          {
            "name": "[concat('VMDiagnosticsVmExt','_vmNodeType0Name')]",
            "properties": {
              "type": "IaaSDiagnostics",
              "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
              "protectedSettings": {
                "storageAccountName": "[variables('applicationDiagnosticsStorageAccountName')]",
                "storageAccountKey": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('applicationDiagnosticsStorageAccountName')),'2015-05-01-preview').key1]",
                "storageAccountEndPoint": "https://core.windows.net/"
              },
              "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics",
              "settings": {
                "WadCfg": {
                  "DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration": {
                    "overallQuotaInMB": "50000",
                    "EtwProviders": {
                      "EtwEventSourceProviderConfiguration": [
                        {
                          "provider": "Microsoft-ServiceFabric-Actors",
                          "scheduledTransferKeywordFilter": "1",
                          "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT5M",
                          "DefaultEvents": {
                            "eventDestination": "ServiceFabricReliableActorEventTable"
                          }
                        },                           
                        {
                          "provider": "Microsoft-ServiceFabric-Services",
                          "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT5M",
                          "DefaultEvents": {
                            "eventDestination": "ServiceFabricReliableServiceEventTable"
                          }
                        }
                      ],
                      "EtwManifestProviderConfiguration": [
                        {
                          "provider": "cbd93bc2-71e5-4566-b3a7-595d8eeca6e8",
                          "scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter": "Information",
                          "scheduledTransferKeywordFilter": "4611686018427387904",
                          "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT5M",
                          "DefaultEvents": {
                            "eventDestination": "ServiceFabricSystemEventTable"
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                },
                "StorageAccount": "[variables('applicationDiagnosticsStorageAccountName')]"
              },
              "typeHandlerVersion": "1.5"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "networkProfile": {},
      "osProfile": {},
      "storageProfile": {}
    }
  },
  "sku": {
    "name": "[variables('vmNodeType0Size')]",
    "capacity": "5",
    "tier": "Basic"
  },
  "tags": {
    "resourceType": "Service Fabric",
    "clusterName": "[parameters('clusterName')]"
  }
}
```

which works by sending all the build in events of service fabric to EWT tables in blob storage.

Then when creating a new service fabric application in visual studio a new event source for application logging is created:

```
[EventSource(Name = "MyCompany-MessageProcessor.ServiceFabricHost-StatelessServiceProcessor")]
internal sealed class ServiceEventSource : EventSource
{
    ...
}
```

which is not transferred to table storage.

Googling `IaaSDiagnostics WadCfg EtwProviders` do not provide any documentation on how these work.

How do we enable the EventSouces to be transferred to table storage with all the build in events?

Comment: Bad edit, it made a mistake in the title. Good job on reviewer for just pressing accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Side by side to the `Microsoft-ServiceFabric-Actors` and `Microsoft-ServiceFabric-Services` providers one can add your own event source names.

```
"EtwEventSourceProviderConfiguration": [
  {
    "provider": "Microsoft-ServiceFabric-Actors",
    "scheduledTransferKeywordFilter": "1",
    "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT5M",
    "DefaultEvents": {
      "eventDestination": "ServiceFabricReliableActorEventTable"
    }
  },
  {
    "provider": "S-Innovations-Azure-MessageProcessor-ServiceFabric",
    "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT5M",
    "DefaultEvents": {
      "eventDestination": "SInnovationsServiceFabricMessageProcessor"
    }
  },
  {
    "provider": "Microsoft-ServiceFabric-Services",
    "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT5M",
    "DefaultEvents": {
      "eventDestination": "ServiceFabricReliableServiceEventTable"
    }
  }
],
```

and I choose to combine the two sample EventSources from Services and Actors into one:

```
namespace SInnovations.Azure.MessageProcessor.ServiceFabric.Tracing
{
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics.Tracing;
    using System.Fabric;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors;
    using Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Runtime;

    [EventSource(Name = "S-Innovations-Azure-MessageProcessor-ServiceFabric")]
    internal sealed class ServiceFabricEventSource : EventSource
    {
        public static readonly ServiceFabricEventSource Current = new ServiceFabricEventSource();

        static ServiceFabricEventSource()
        {
            // A workaround for the problem where ETW activities do not get tracked until Tasks infrastructure is initialized.
            // This problem will be fixed in .NET Framework 4.6.2.
            Task.Run(() => { }).Wait();
        }

        // Instance constructor is private to enforce singleton semantics
        private ServiceFabricEventSource() : base() { }

        #region Keywords
        // Event keywords can be used to categorize events. 
        // Each keyword is a bit flag. A single event can be associated with multiple keywords (via EventAttribute.Keywords property).
        // Keywords must be defined as a public class named 'Keywords' inside EventSource that uses them.
        public static class Keywords
        {
            public const EventKeywords HostInitialization = (EventKeywords)0x1L;
            public const EventKeywords Requests = (EventKeywords)0x2L;
            public const EventKeywords ServiceInitialization = (EventKeywords)0x4L;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Events
        // Define an instance method for each event you want to record and apply an [Event] attribute to it.
        // The method name is the name of the event.
        // Pass any parameters you want to record with the event (only primitive integer types, DateTime, Guid & string are allowed).
        // Each event method implementation should check whether the event source is enabled, and if it is, call WriteEvent() method to raise the event.
        // The number and types of arguments passed to every event method must exactly match what is passed to WriteEvent().
        // Put [NonEvent] attribute on all methods that do not define an event.
        // For more information see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventsource.aspx

        [NonEvent]
        public void Message(string message, params object[] args)
        {
            if (this.IsEnabled())
            {
                string finalMessage = string.Format(message, args);
                Message(finalMessage);
            }
        }

        private const int MessageEventId = 1;
        [Event(MessageEventId, Level = EventLevel.Informational, Message = "{0}")]
        public void Message(string message)
        {
            if (this.IsEnabled())
            {
                WriteEvent(MessageEventId, message);
            }
        }

        [NonEvent]
        public void ActorMessage(StatelessActor actor, string message, params object[] args)
        {
            if (this.IsEnabled())
            {
                string finalMessage = string.Format(message, args);
                ActorMessage(
                    actor.GetType().ToString(),
                    actor.Id.ToString(),
                    actor.ActorService.ServiceInitializationParameters.CodePackageActivationContext.ApplicationTypeName,
                    actor.ActorService.ServiceInitializationParameters.CodePackageActivationContext.ApplicationName,
                    actor.ActorService.ServiceInitializationParameters.ServiceTypeName,
                    actor.ActorService.ServiceInitializationParameters.ServiceName.ToString(),
                    actor.ActorService.ServiceInitializationParameters.PartitionId,
                    actor.ActorService.ServiceInitializationParameters.InstanceId,
                    FabricRuntime.GetNodeContext().NodeName,
                    finalMessage);
            }
        }

        [NonEvent]
        public void ActorMessage(StatefulActorBase actor, string message, params object[] args)
        {
            if (this.IsEnabled())
            {
                string finalMessage = string.Format(message, args);
                ActorMessage(
                    actor.GetType().ToString(),
                    actor.Id.ToString(),
                    actor.ActorService.ServiceInitializationParameters.CodePackageActivationContext.ApplicationTypeName,
                    actor.ActorService.ServiceInitializationParameters.CodePackageActivationContext.ApplicationName,
                    actor.ActorService.ServiceInitializationParameters.ServiceTypeName,
                    actor.ActorService.ServiceInitializationParameters.ServiceName.ToString(),
                    actor.ActorService.ServiceInitializationParameters.PartitionId,
                    actor.ActorService.ServiceInitializationParameters.ReplicaId,
                    FabricRuntime.GetNodeContext().NodeName,
                    finalMessage);
            }
        }

        [NonEvent]
        public void ServiceMessage(StatelessService service, string message, params object[] args)
        {
            if (this.IsEnabled())
            {
                string finalMessage = string.Format(message, args);
                ServiceMessage(
                    service.ServiceInitializationParameters.ServiceName.ToString(),
                    service.ServiceInitializationParameters.ServiceTypeName,
                    service.ServiceInitializationParameters.InstanceId,
                    service.ServiceInitializationParameters.PartitionId,
                    service.ServiceInitializationParameters.CodePackageActivationContext.ApplicationName,
                    service.ServiceInitializationParameters.CodePackageActivationContext.ApplicationTypeName,
                    FabricRuntime.GetNodeContext().NodeName,
                    finalMessage);
            }
        }

        [NonEvent]
        public void ServiceMessage(StatefulService service, string message, params object[] args)
        {
            if (this.IsEnabled())
            {
                string finalMessage = string.Format(message, args);
                ServiceMessage(
                    service.ServiceInitializationParameters.ServiceName.ToString(),
                    service.ServiceInitializationParameters.ServiceTypeName,
                    service.ServiceInitializationParameters.ReplicaId,
                    service.ServiceInitializationParameters.PartitionId,
                    service.ServiceInitializationParameters.CodePackageActivationContext.ApplicationName,
                    service.ServiceInitializationParameters.CodePackageActivationContext.ApplicationTypeName,
                    FabricRuntime.GetNodeContext().NodeName,
                    finalMessage);
            }
        }


        // For very high-frequency events it might be advantageous to raise events using WriteEventCore API.
        // This results in more efficient parameter handling, but requires explicit allocation of EventData structure and unsafe code.
        // To enable this code path, define UNSAFE conditional compilation symbol and turn on unsafe code support in project properties.
        private const int ServiceMessageEventId = 2;
        [Event(ServiceMessageEventId, Level = EventLevel.Informational, Message = "{7}")]
        private
#if UNSAFE
        unsafe
#endif
        void ServiceMessage(
            string serviceName,
            string serviceTypeName,
            long replicaOrInstanceId,
            Guid partitionId,
            string applicationName,
            string applicationTypeName,
            string nodeName,
            string message)
        {
#if !UNSAFE
            WriteEvent(ServiceMessageEventId, serviceName, serviceTypeName, replicaOrInstanceId, partitionId, applicationName, applicationTypeName, nodeName, message);
#else
            const int numArgs = 8;
            fixed (char* pServiceName = serviceName, pServiceTypeName = serviceTypeName, pApplicationName = applicationName, pApplicationTypeName = applicationTypeName, pNodeName = nodeName, pMessage = message)
            {
                EventData* eventData = stackalloc EventData[numArgs];
                eventData[0] = new EventData { DataPointer = (IntPtr) pServiceName, Size = SizeInBytes(serviceName) };
                eventData[1] = new EventData { DataPointer = (IntPtr) pServiceTypeName, Size = SizeInBytes(serviceTypeName) };
                eventData[2] = new EventData { DataPointer = (IntPtr) (&replicaOrInstanceId), Size = sizeof(long) };
                eventData[3] = new EventData { DataPointer = (IntPtr) (&partitionId), Size = sizeof(Guid) };
                eventData[4] = new EventData { DataPointer = (IntPtr) pApplicationName, Size = SizeInBytes(applicationName) };
                eventData[5] = new EventData { DataPointer = (IntPtr) pApplicationTypeName, Size = SizeInBytes(applicationTypeName) };
                eventData[6] = new EventData { DataPointer = (IntPtr) pNodeName, Size = SizeInBytes(nodeName) };
                eventData[7] = new EventData { DataPointer = (IntPtr) pMessage, Size = SizeInBytes(message) };

                WriteEventCore(ServiceMessageEventId, numArgs, eventData);
            }
#endif
        }

        private const int ServiceTypeRegisteredEventId = 3;
        [Event(ServiceTypeRegisteredEventId, Level = EventLevel.Informational, Message = "Service host process {0} registered service type {1}", Keywords = Keywords.ServiceInitialization)]
        public void ServiceTypeRegistered(int hostProcessId, string serviceType)
        {
            WriteEvent(ServiceTypeRegisteredEventId, hostProcessId, serviceType);
        }

        private const int ServiceHostInitializationFailedEventId = 4;
        [Event(ServiceHostInitializationFailedEventId, Level = EventLevel.Error, Message = "Service host initialization failed", Keywords = Keywords.ServiceInitialization)]
        public void ServiceHostInitializationFailed(string exception)
        {
            WriteEvent(ServiceHostInitializationFailedEventId, exception);
        }

        // A pair of events sharing the same name prefix with a "Start"/"Stop" suffix implicitly marks boundaries of an event tracing activity.
        // These activities can be automatically picked up by debugging and profiling tools, which can compute their execution time, child activities,
        // and other statistics.
        private const int ServiceRequestStartEventId = 5;
        [Event(ServiceRequestStartEventId, Level = EventLevel.Informational, Message = "Service request '{0}' started", Keywords = Keywords.Requests)]
        public void ServiceRequestStart(string requestTypeName)
        {
            WriteEvent(ServiceRequestStartEventId, requestTypeName);
        }

        private const int ServiceRequestStopEventId = 6;
        [Event(ServiceRequestStopEventId, Level = EventLevel.Informational, Message = "Service request '{0}' finished", Keywords = Keywords.Requests)]
        public void ServiceRequestStop(string requestTypeName)
        {
            WriteEvent(ServiceRequestStopEventId, requestTypeName);
        }

        private const int ServiceRequestFailedEventId = 7;
        [Event(ServiceRequestFailedEventId, Level = EventLevel.Error, Message = "Service request '{0}' failed", Keywords = Keywords.Requests)]
        public void ServiceRequestFailed(string requestTypeName, string exception)
        {
            WriteEvent(ServiceRequestFailedEventId, exception);
        }

        // For very high-frequency events it might be advantageous to raise events using WriteEventCore API.
        // This results in more efficient parameter handling, but requires explicit allocation of EventData structure and unsafe code.
        // To enable this code path, define UNSAFE conditional compilation symbol and turn on unsafe code support in project properties.
        private const int ActorMessageEventId = 8;
        [Event(ActorMessageEventId, Level = EventLevel.Informational, Message = "{9}")]
        private
#if UNSAFE
            unsafe
#endif
            void ActorMessage(
            string actorType,
            string actorId,
            string applicationTypeName,
            string applicationName,
            string serviceTypeName,
            string serviceName,
            Guid partitionId,
            long replicaOrInstanceId,
            string nodeName,
            string message)
        {
#if !UNSAFE
            WriteEvent(
                    ActorMessageEventId,
                    actorType,
                    actorId,
                    applicationTypeName,
                    applicationName,
                    serviceTypeName,
                    serviceName,
                    partitionId,
                    replicaOrInstanceId,
                    nodeName,
                    message);
#else
                const int numArgs = 10;
                fixed (char* pActorType = actorType, pActorId = actorId, pApplicationTypeName = applicationTypeName, pApplicationName = applicationName, pServiceTypeName = serviceTypeName, pServiceName = serviceName, pNodeName = nodeName, pMessage = message)
                {
                    EventData* eventData = stackalloc EventData[numArgs];
                    eventData[0] = new EventData { DataPointer = (IntPtr) pActorType, Size = SizeInBytes(actorType) };
                    eventData[1] = new EventData { DataPointer = (IntPtr) pActorId, Size = SizeInBytes(actorId) };
                    eventData[2] = new EventData { DataPointer = (IntPtr) pApplicationTypeName, Size = SizeInBytes(applicationTypeName) };
                    eventData[3] = new EventData { DataPointer = (IntPtr) pApplicationName, Size = SizeInBytes(applicationName) };
                    eventData[4] = new EventData { DataPointer = (IntPtr) pServiceTypeName, Size = SizeInBytes(serviceTypeName) };
                    eventData[5] = new EventData { DataPointer = (IntPtr) pServiceName, Size = SizeInBytes(serviceName) };
                    eventData[6] = new EventData { DataPointer = (IntPtr) (&partitionId), Size = sizeof(Guid) };
                    eventData[7] = new EventData { DataPointer = (IntPtr) (&replicaOrInstanceId), Size = sizeof(long) };
                    eventData[8] = new EventData { DataPointer = (IntPtr) pNodeName, Size = SizeInBytes(nodeName) };
                    eventData[9] = new EventData { DataPointer = (IntPtr) pMessage, Size = SizeInBytes(message) };

                    WriteEventCore(ActorMessageEventId, numArgs, eventData);
                }
#endif
        }

        private const int ActorHostInitializationFailedEventId = 9;
        [Event(ActorHostInitializationFailedEventId, Level = EventLevel.Error, Message = "Actor host initialization failed", Keywords = Keywords.HostInitialization)]
        public void ActorHostInitializationFailed(string exception)
        {
            WriteEvent(ActorHostInitializationFailedEventId, exception);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Private Methods
#if UNSAFE
            private int SizeInBytes(string s)
            {
                if (s == null)
                {
                    return 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    return (s.Length + 1) * sizeof(char);
                }
            }
#endif
        #endregion
    }
}
```